# C#/.NET - WinForms - Instantiate a Form without showing it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, visibility

I am changing the Visibility of a Form to false during the load event AND the form still shows itself. What is the right event to tie this.Visible = false; to? I'd like to instantiate the Form1 without showing it.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm baffled by how many people gave answers in this thread without checking the results. Hide();
Visible = false; none of these things work in this scenario. Its not like other forms, its the MAIN form, and it will be shown no matter what you do. People here need to think before giving bogus answers. And BTW, there is no Visible property for the Main Form in Visual Studio 2010. Its simply not there at all.

Comment: @Draek, Good point. But you can achieve similar functionality using a combination of properties  named ShowInTaskbar and WindowState. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Regardless of how much you try to set the Visible property before the form has been shown, it will pop up. As I understand it, this is because it is the MainForm of the current ApplicationContext. One way to have the form automatically load, but not show at application startup is to alter the Main method. By default, it looks something like this (.NET 2.0 VS2005):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

If you instead do something like this, the application will start, load your form and run, but the form will not show:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    Application.Run();        

}
```

I am not entirely sure how this is useful, but I hope you know that ;o)

Update: it seems that you do not need to set the Visible property to false, or supply an ApplicationContext instance (that will be automatically created for you "under the hood"). Shortened the code accordingly.

Comment: +1 good idea. Gotcha. Sounds like its the Application.Run that is the culprit.

Comment: Yes, out of curiosity I checked what happens under the hood, and ApplicationContext will set Visible=true on the MainForm, if there is any. If you call Application.Run with a form instance as input, a new ApplicationContext is created that gets the form assigned to the MainForm property.

Comment: The trouble with this solution is that closing the form does not close the application.  Therefore you must compensate by calling Application.Exit() on the FormClose.  Unless ofcourse your application uses more than one form, in which case you'll need to be a bit more intelligent.  Luckily mine only uses one form and a system tray icon, so the example above works just fine.

Comment: I found a better way to solve  this problem which I added as another answer.

Comment: I don't know why this answer marked as answer, because on my computer this example doesn't work. Form still visible...

Comment: @AnatoliiGumennyi Can you provide details on how you did? I just retried this (VS2013) and the form does not show for me.

Comment: Thank you. This finally worked for me after trying many other different examples.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but I just stumbled upon it and am pretty surprised no one has mentioned [`SetVisibleCore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setvisiblecore%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
bool isVisibleCore = false;
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
{
    base.SetVisibleCore(isVisibleCore);
}
```

In that code snippet, as long as `isVisibleCore` remains false, the form will remain invisible. If it's set to false when the form is instantiated, you won't get that brief flash of visibility that you'd get if you set `Visible = false` in the Shown event.

Comment: this did not created the form

Comment: when i have created the form outside application.run and did not do form.show(); (witch probably have events to create components at first show). so the components on the form did not created fully. and when i tried to interact with them i got an error component did not initialized. same error was when i have overridden setvisible or set the form to invisible at the beginning.

Comment: what worked is to create the form and show it with window state minimized and only then hide it and set windows state to normal. (this time the onload event was fired) after trayicon click had to set left top height and width in anyone of them was wrong like -32000

Comment: Warning : this prevents not only the "Shown" event (which you may expect) but also "Load" and maybe others. Be aware of it. They are  raised on first call to base.SetVisibleCore(true).

Comment: **NB** this approach will prevent closing the form (and other normal lifecycle events). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4556649/67392 for a better approach.

Comment: @Richard, What is **NB**?

Comment: "NB" == "Nota Bene" which is, essentially, Latin for "important note". For more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene

Comment: Ah, okay. :) And yes, that was an important note. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 10):

It took me some time to find a properly working Solution.

Set the properties named WindowState to Minimized  and ShowInTaskbar to False under properties window. Once your form is completly loaded,  Call below lines of code.

```
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        //this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal;
```

PS: This solution is Tested on Visual C# 2008 Express Edition

Answer (score 3):

How about setting the Opacity property to 0 on design and back to 100 when you want to show the form?

Comment: With this approach the form will still be accessible if the user uses alt + tab.

Answer (score 2):

a solution i can live with
so the form is created and on_load is called on createtion. 
set  WindowState  to minimize then on load set visible to false and windowstate to normal

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.Visible = false;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

what did not worked:

the SetVisibleCore override solution did not created the form

as also the

```
Application {
 Form1 f = new Form1();
 Application.Run();
```

):

Answer (score 2):

For a flicker-free Shown solution, also set the form's location off-screen during load:

```
private Point startuplocation;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.startuplocation = this.Location;
    this.Location = new Point(-1000, -1000);
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) //fires first time shown
{
    this.Visible = false;
    this.Location = this.startuplocation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create an instance of `Form1` and do not call methods to show/display it. But I bet you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try on the VisibleChanged event.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest would be to instantiate the form in an event the precedes the _Show event, such as the constructor, after the IntializeComponent() call.

Comment: I think perhaps you meant hide rather than instantiate, correct? In any event (no pun intended), you'd have to ensure that wherever you're calling it occurs AFTER the call that makes the form visible, but before it actually BECOMES visible.

Comment: Actually I suggested an approach to Initialize whatever necessary prior to Showing the form.

Answer (score 1):

The shown event may give you want you want.  Although the form will "flash" for a second before hiding.

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your main form, there may not be a better place then the Shown event. But in that case you will get flicker.

I couldn't find a good place to stop a running main form from showing at least quickly.  Even a timer activated in the load event won't do it.

If it is a secondary form just create it but don't show it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
this.Hide();
```

in the `form_load` or `form_activated` events

Comment: Just FYI, this doesn't work when used in the form_load event, but does work in the form_activated event, albeit showing the form for a split-second before hiding.

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibilty on the constructor, after init and then this.Show() later

Answer (score 0):

InitializeComponent() is setting this.Visible = true, since you specified that the form should be visible in the designer (or it defaulted to that). You should set Visible to false in the designer, and it won't be called by InitializeComponent(). You can then make it visible any time you like.

Answer (score 0):

Having `.Visible = false` or `Hide()` in the `Load` event will cause your form to show briefly, as there is time between when it becomes physically visible and when the `Load` event gets fired, in spite of the fact that the documentation says the contrary.

Are you calling `Show()` or `ShowDialog()` somewhere? I'm not sure if this behavior is still present, but at least in past versions of the framework a call to `ShowDialog()` did not trigger the `Load` event, so perhaps that is your issue (though I think calling `ShowDialog()` then hiding a modal form would be a bad practice!)

If you have to have the handle created (and the handles for controls) for whatever it is you're trying to do, a better idea would be to set the `StartLocation` to `Manual`, then set the `Position` property to an offscreen location. This will create and show the form, while making it invisible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the really one elegant way in perspective to your code than your applications visual is to flicker the form by hiding in the constructor/load event.

Answer (score 0):

I set these three property settings for the form:

```
ShowInTaskbar = false
ShowIcon = false
WindowState = Minimized
```