# What code controls the startup of a WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf

More specifically, how could I [setup a startup sequence like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617784/how-to-start-the-application-directly-in-system-tray-net-c/1617821#1617821) in WPF where no window is shown at start, but a notification icon is present?

Comment: Sorry, haven't you referenced your answer? May be I do not understand what you want to do instead.

Comment: @Markus that answer is specifically and only applicable to WinForms. WPF has a different startup mechanism, so that answer isn't applicable here (there is no `Program.cs` for instance)

Comment: @Markus: There is no access to the `Main` method in a normal WPF application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `StartupUri` attribute from the `Application` root tag of your App.xaml file and add the code you want to execute in the [Application.Startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) event handler.

Comment: It's worth noting that in an application that you're doing something like this in, you probably want to set `ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;` as Eamon mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 14):

To run, WPF requires an `Application` object.  when you execute [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.run.aspx) on that object, the application goes into an infinite loop: the event loop responsible for handling user input and any other OS signals.

In other words, you *can* include a custom Main function in a WPF app just fine; it merely needs to look something like this:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    //include custom startup code here

    var app = new MyApplication();//Application or a subclass thereof
    var win = new MyWindow();//Window or a subclass thereof
    app.Run(win); //do WPF init and start windows message pump.
}
```

Here's an article about some of the gotcha's using this approach: [The Wpf Application class: Overview and Gotcha](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-wpf-application-class-overview-and-gotcha/).  In particular, you'll probably want to set things like `Application.ShutdownMode`.  This approach leaves you free to do whatever you want before any WPF code runs - but, more importantly, I hope it elucidates how WPF apps start.