# How to Show an External WPF Before MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF application calls upon a separate project to handle a login process BEFORE the Main Window in my application is shown.  This creates a problem and causes "Application Shutdown" errors because the FIRST window in the application has closed.  How can I handle the login process BEFORE my Main Window is shown?  Every search I find comes up with references to Prism or MEF... which I cannot use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control everything from the very start of your application, you need to create your own main method and use this as "start object" (see project properties). [More details can be found in another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430432/what-code-controls-the-startup-of-a-wpf-application), but this is its essence:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Do anything you like before running the main window.
    // ...

    // Proceed with usual application flow.
    var app = new MyApplication();
    var win = new MyWindow();
    app.Run(win);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the application shutdown error, you can change [Application.ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [OnExplicitShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shutdownmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And explicitly call [Application.Shutdown Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to close your application when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding code to the App.xaml.cs file?  There are places you can place code in there that runs before the main window is opened.  In addition to a constructor, there's the `Startup` event that you can assign a handler to in the App.xaml file:

```
<Application x:Class="CarSystem.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         DispatcherUnhandledException="App_DispatcherUnhandledException" 
         Exit="Application_Exit" 
         Startup="Application_Startup" 
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

And, of course there's the Main method in the same file that you could throw code into, as well.