# How to "restore" SynchronizationContext when using custom startup?

Tags: wpf, synchronizationcontext

My app works fine, but now I wanted to have custom startup, so I could catch any errors, add my logging from the start, etc.

So I used approach as shown in this answer [What code controls the startup of a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430432/what-code-controls-the-startup-of-a-wpf-application)

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    //include custom startup code here

    var app = new MyApplication();//Application or a subclass thereof
    var win = new MyWindow();//Window or a subclass thereof
    app.Run(win); //do WPF init and start windows message pump.
}
```

It works fine with one exception -- `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null. And I need it :-)

So how to correctly make custom startup and have synchronization context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create your own `Main` method. Override the `OnStartup` method in your `App.xaml.cs` file:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var win = new MyWindow();
        win.Show();
    }
}
```

Then you will get a `SynchronizationContext` as usual.

Don't forget to remove the `StartupUri` attribute from the `<Application>` root element of your `App.xaml` file.

Comment: Great, I have all the features I wanted, thank you very much!