# send files to usb automatic whenUSB inserted using c#

Tags: c#, usb, background-process

I'm trying to make an **auto-backup** app using C#..

All it has to do is simply to start running when I **insert the USB** drive, then **automatically** backup one - as a start - folder to the USB Drive..

Now I know my way around with files using c#, what I don't know is how to detect the insertion of the USB, and "*if needed*" how to make the app run in background?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following reference to detect the pluging of the USB drive:
http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/detecting-usb-devices-using-c.html

About the running the application in background, you can check this SO question:
[How to start the application directly in system tray? (.NET C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617784/how-to-start-the-application-directly-in-system-tray-net-c)